# Why can't the type be deduced in this template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enable-if

```
template<typename T>
std::istream & read(std::istream & istr, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, T>::type & value)
{
    return istr.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
}

int main() 
{
    int x;
    read(cin, x); // error here
}


error C2783: 'std::istream &read(std::istream &,std::enable_if<std::tr1::is_pod<_Ty>::value,T>::type &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

It works if I specify read<int>.  Is there any way to get it to deduce the type from the argument?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
std::istream & read(std::istream & istr, T value, 
                    typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type* = 0)
{
    return istr.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
}
```

Or

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, std::istream>::type &
read(std::istream & istr, T value)
{
    return istr.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(T));
}
```

The reason yours does not work is because it is not sufficient for determining T if you know the type of the argument. What if `enable_if` would be a template like the following?

```
template<int N, typename T> struct A { typedef int type; };
```

Any `T` in `<std::is_pod<T>::value, T>` would do it. <s>In general,</s> a function parameter type formed by `...T...::type` is called a non-deduced context and can't be used to deduce `T`.

Comment: You say "in general", is there a specific case otherwise?

Comment: @GMan I can't think of another case. Fixed.